# Which is the best way of dealing with transformation layer between dto and dao in scala?

Tags: scala, dao, transformation, dto

We are working in an app in scala and we would like to keep the transformation layer as thin as possible.

We would like to convert all the DAO objects to DTO objects and the other way around. In the beginning they all will have the same fields, but in the future we are almost sure they won't be the same. So, we want to have a default implementation, `EntityTransformerImpl`, but we would like to be able to implement customs `EntityTransformer`.

We have came up with this solution. It's not that bad but we think it might be rather slow as we are using reflection to load the class and create the new objects.

```scala
package com.triplea.business.transformer

import org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtils
import com.triplea.dao.dto.CourseDTO
import com.triplea.business.entity.Course

class EntityTransformerImpl[T, E] extends EntityTransformer[T, E] {

    def transformToDTO(entity: T): E = {
        val clazz = java.lang.Class.forName(manifest.asInstanceOf[E].getClass().getName())
        val ctr = clazz.getConstructor()
        var dto: E = ctr.newInstance().asInstanceOf[E]
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(dto, entity)
        dto
    }

    def transformListToDTO(entities: List[T]): List[E] = {
        entities.map(e => transformToDTO(e))
    }

    def transformListToEntity(dtos: List[E]): List[T] = {
        dtos.map(e => transformToEntity()
    }

    def transformOptionToDTO(entities: Option[T]): Option[E] = {
        entities.map(e => transformToDTO(e))
    }

    def transformOptionToEntity(dtos: Option[E]): Option[T] = {
        dtos.map(e => transformToEntity(e))
    }

}
```

Do you think is a good solution? Do you have any new ideas for this implementation?

Comment: If they have the same fields, why would you want to have two classes for it?

Comment: They are going to belong to diferent layers, DAOs for Data Access Layer and DTOs for Business layer. As the tool evolve classes for diferent layer may evolve as well, and the may have diferent attributes or they might compound using diferent rules.

Comment: Sounds like a bad case of YAGNI to me.